# how to pass in state parameter to ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Trying to pass on a parameter to my ui router:

```
$state.go('orderDetail', {myParam: {accountID: $scope.selectedAccount}})
```

In my `stateprovider` the `orderDetail` state looks like this:

```
.state('orderDetail', {
    templateUrl: 'modules/common/orders/partials/detail.html?referrer',
    controller: 'OrderDetailCtrl',
    url: '/detail/:myParam',
    resolve: {

        orderDetails: function (myservice, configService, $stateParams) {
            console.log('resolve');
            var referrer = $stateParams.myParam;
            debugger;
            console.log('stateParm', referrer.accountID);
            console.log('order detail resolving');
            //todo remove hardcoded
            return myservice.getDetail(configService.config('mock_order_detail').url + '?accountId=2233');
        }
    }
});
```

However `console.log('stateParm', referrer.accountID);` shows up as `undefined`. How can I pass in the `accountID` param?

Comment: the `:myParam` you're taking in the $stateParams is a string, which comes from the splat in the url matcher `url: /detail/:myParam`. This string won't have an `accountID` property on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recognize the state that `myParam` is object, you need to define its default value inside your state `params` option, by assigning `null` or any default value you want for it.

**Code**

```
.state('orderDetail', {
      templateUrl: 'modules/common/orders/partials/detail.html?referrer',
      controller: 'OrderDetailCtrl',
      url: '/detail/:myParam',
      resolve: {
           //resolve code here
      }
      params: {
          'myParam': null
      }
}
```

> To make above changes effective you Should update ui-router version to **`0.2.13`**

[**Github Issue Link**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/983#issuecomment-63982316)

Comment: I forgot to say that the state.go statement is in a another controller where the accountId is set. It then goes to the stateprovider and that is where I would like to read the passed on param ie accountId

Comment: @Leeuwtje did you tried the way I suggested...? I don't understand your point now..could you update your question with more details..Thanks :)

Comment: did you find anything on this??

Answer (score 0):

$stateParams accepts only string, however you could stringify your object as pass it as myParam

```
$state.go('orderDetail', {myParam: angular.fromJson({accountID: $scope.selectedAccount})})
```

and then

```
.state('orderDetail', {
    templateUrl: 'modules/common/orders/partials/detail.html?referrer',
    controller: 'OrderDetailCtrl',
    url: '/detail/:myParam',
    resolve: {
        orderDetails: function (myservice, configService, $stateParams) {
            var referrer = angular.toJson($stateParams.myParam);
            return myservice.getDetail(configService.config('mock_order_detail').url + '?accountId=2233');
        }
    }
});
```

But i don't recommend using stringified objects, better use a service as bridge for states, just because makes ugly URL and not secure, internal state must be hidden from user i belive

Comment: it does not pass in the param it still comes back as "[object object]" something like this?